# metadata-generation-failed while installing Conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda

I was trying to install conda using pip in Command Prompt, I search Everywhere related to this error but I found Nothing that can help me with the problem.

```
pip install conda
```

but I got this error:

```
Collecting conda
  Using cached conda-4.3.16.tar.gz (299 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pycosat>=0.6.1 in c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
(from conda) (0.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.12.4 in c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-package
s (from conda) (2.26.0)
Collecting ruamel.yaml>=0.11.14
  Using cached ruamel.yaml-0.17.21-py3-none-any.whl (109 kB)
Collecting conda
  Using cached conda-4.3.13.tar.gz (370 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
  Using cached conda-4.2.7.tar.gz (235 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-89w5h0p1\conda_ae1fc222c1a04f2ca50dbd3c45396cdf\setup.py", line 32, in <module>
          from conda._vendor.auxlib import packaging  # NOQA
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'auxlib'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Please help me to find a solution for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.

the problem in line

```
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'auxlib'
```

so I just install `auxlib` by using

```
pip install auxlib
```

and then my problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**pip is not the correct way to install conda**

See [the pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/conda/)

> WARNING: Using pip install conda or easy_install conda will not give you conda as a standalone application. Currently supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda installer.

Comment: but I need Conda support in cmd, so I was trying to install conda using pip.

Comment: You will need to use miniconda or anaconda then

Comment: I already use those but they are not accessible in `cmd`

Comment: In your cmd, just run `call “<miniconda/anaconda root>\Scripts\activate”`. Replace the part in `<>` with the actual directory of your conda

Comment: thanks bro now I resolve this problem